# On properly implementing complex service layers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, design-patterns, dao

I have the following situation:

Three concrete service classes implement a service interface: one is for persistence, the other deals with notifications, the third deals with adding points to specific actions (gamification). The interface has roughly the following structure:

```
public interface IPhotoService {
   void upload();
   Photo get(Long id);
   void like(Long id);
   //etc...
}
```

I did not want to mix the three types of logic into one service (or even worse, in the controller class) because I want to be able to change them (or shut them) without any problems. The problem comes when I have to inject a concrete service into the controller to use. Usually, I create a fourth class, named roughly `ApplicationNamePhotoService`, which implements the same interface, and works as a wrapper (mediator) between the other three services, which gets input from the controller, and calls each service correspondingly. It is a working approach, though one, which creates a lot of boilerplate code.

Is this the right approach? Currently, I am not aware of a better one, although I will highly appreciate to know if  it is possible to declare the execution sequence declaratively (in the context) and to inject the controller with and on-the fly generated wrapper instance.

Also, it would be nice to cache some stuff between the three services. For example, all are using DAOs, i.e. making sometimes the same calls to the DB over and over again. If all the logic were into one place that could have been avoided, but now... I know that it is possible to enable some request or session based caching. Can you suggest me some example code? BTW, I am using Hibernate for the persistence part. Is there already some caching provided (probably, if they reside in the same transaction or something - with that one I am totally lost)

Comment: are you saying 3 implementations for 1 interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service layer should consist of classes with methods that are units of work with actions that belong in the same transaction. It sounds like you are mixing service classes when they could be in the same class and method. You can inject service classes into one another when required too, rather than create another "mediator".

It is perfectly acceptable to "mix the three types of logic", in fact it is preferable if they form an expected use case/unit of work

Cache-ing I would look to use [eh cache](http://ehcache.org/) which is, I believe, well integrated with hibernate.

Comment: Well, not really. If I'd used one service class to do this, it would have been a blob of spaghetti.

Comment: I didn't mean only have one class.  The code should be separated into units of work.